# What is the name of this spider I found in The Netherlands?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

This spider is smaller than 1 mm and fast. 
The spider has tiny hairs on orange coloured legs. The backside of the spider is dark-brownish and has a small red stripe in the middle. I have taken pictures magnifying 25x using a lens of some watchmaker glasses. As a reference the lens of the lamp shining on the spider is 6mm.
Found inside my house on the second floor on the attic.

The location is [North-Brabant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Brabant), The Netherlands, [location on maps](https://goo.gl/maps/JY7FtqZBBMpMvRpK7).

I have searched all over the internet but I keep coming back to mites which this specimen doesn't resemble.

Unfortunately the camera isn't as good as my eyes, although a little zooming is possible.
[image]

The spider skittered around again today and I managed to take a picture, unfortunately not a zoomed one but maybe some characteristics will be recognized.

[image]

Comment: I think it is indeed a mite - have a look at genus Anystis or Tetranychus.

Comment: @JimN Yes that is it! I never thought to search for spider mites. Would you like to write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking at a spider mite of the genus Anystis or Tetranychus. Both of these have The Netherlands in their range.

Here is an info page on the two genuses, includes a map of observations and a gallery of photos that you can even filter to only view images from a certain range. You can also filter the gallery to group photos into species categories.

Anystis: https://inaturalist.ca/taxa/249515-Anystis
Tetranychus: https://inaturalist.ca/taxa/203334-Tetranychus